# Rudin PMA question

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $g$ is a real function on $\mathbb R^1$, with bounded derivative (say $|g'|\le \mathbf M$). Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$, and define $f(x)= x+\epsilon g(x)$. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one if $\epsilon$ is small enough.

I know (or think I know) how to do this. If $\epsilon \lt \frac1 M$, then $\mathbf M \epsilon\lt1$, and $f'(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$. Therefore $x_1 \ne x_2 $ implies that $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$. (If $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ for some $x_1 \ne x_2$, by Rolle's theorem there exists $x_0$ in ($x_1, x_2)$ satisfying $f'(x_0)=0$, contradicting $f'(x) \gt0$ for all $x$.)

I have two questions: (1) Why does Rudin say we're dealing with $\mathbb R^1$, not $\mathbb R^2$? (2) Are we to assume that $g(x)$ is differential everywhere in its domain? My use of Rolle's theorem assumes it is differentiable everywhere, and I don't know how to proceed without making this assumption.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sorry, caffeine deficit. I read $f(x)+ \epsilon g(x)$.

Comment: I knew it was something like that, @copper.hat.

Comment: Yes, $g$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @DanielFischer: My mind is a little scrambled from trying to unravel my daughter's middle school geometry :-).

Comment: And one takes $\mathbb{R}^1$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^n$ for simplicity. The analogous things hold in higher dimensions, but it's simpler in dimension $1$.

Comment: @copper.hat That requires a strong dose of single malt to set it straight again.

Comment: @copper.hat But usually Rudin is explicit about the his assumptions: other problems from this same chapter list the assumptions (sometimes quite a few) before asking the student to prove this or that, and differentiability is often one of those assumptions. How do we know that we're to assume that g is differentiable everywhere?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I need an unbounded supply...

Comment: @Ryan: I agree that it is bothersome (details like this delay me regularly), but when he write that the derivative is bounded, the existence of the derivative can be presumed.

Comment: Yes: "with bounded derivative" means, _a fortiori_, "with derivative".

Comment: But the ambiguity lies in the fact that, strictly speaking, having a bounded derivative doesn't guarantee differentiability everywhere. $f(x)=|x| \implies |f'(x)|\le1$, but of course $f$ isn't differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment. The point is to illustrate Daniel's remark regarding simplicity.

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x) = x+\epsilon g(x)$ and $\sup_x \|{\partial g(x) \over \partial x} \| \le M$. Choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon M < 1$.

Then we see that $f(x) = y$ **iff** $\phi_y(x) = x$, where $\phi_y(x) = y-\epsilon g(x)$. Furthermore, $\|{\partial \phi_y(x) \over \partial x} \| \le \epsilon M < 1$, hence $\phi_y$ is a contraction and so the contraction mapping theorem shows that $\phi_y$ has a unique fixed point. It follows that $f$ is injective (and surjective, for that matter).

Also, since ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = I + \epsilon {\partial g(x) \over \partial x}$ is invertible (since${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} v = 0$ implies $v=0$),  the inverse function theorem shows that $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question:
i) In $\Bbb R^2$ LMV theorem does not have this equality form.What can you conclude from here?
ii) $g$ should be differentiable in whole the domain because you have to show $1-1$ in the domain. Roughly speaking its a global property.
So, from $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ what will you get??